# Как запустить анимацию AnimationDrawable в customView?

Tags: customview, android, анимация, view

Доброго времени суток. Вопрос по программирвоанию под андроид. Не могу пробиться в этом месте: имеется кастом класс, унаследованный от `View`, в нем определен некий `drawableAnimation=new AnimationDrawable()`, занимающий лишь часть канваса. Необходимо, чтобы по ивенту (например, клик в определенную область компонента) происходил запуск и отрисовка на канвасе анимации, опредленной в `drawableAnimation`. Естественно, просто засунуть его (`drawableAnimation`) в `onDraw()` не получится - будет рисоваться лишь первый фрейм анмиции или вобще ничего. Насколько я понимаю, надо "вешать" на `drawableAnimation callBack` от самого `CustomView`, чтобы он вызывал `onDraw()` при рисовании самого себя, но как это сделать правильно я не нашел.

Извиняюсь, если вопрос ламерский, чтение документации и гугление не помогло. Спасибо за ответы.

Comment: `customView.invalidate()`?

Comment: обновлять View-компоненты я умею:),вопрос как в этом компоненте отрисовать анимацию, сохраненную в AnimationDrawable - уточню, анимацию не как фон, а как часть канваса View.